# Memory location vs addresses

Tags: variables, memory

I have been on the concept of memory addresses and memory locations for a while now and i want to clarify some aspects that seem a bit confusing

- Is a memory address the memory location itself or is it just a pointer to the memory location - **identifier**
  the space reserved for a variable when i declare let's say
  `int a;` the space said to be reserved for a variable is that it's address or that is just a **memory location** with an **address** and labelled with a **variable**

Comment: Is a house address the house itself or a pointer to the house? Should answer that one. As for the rest, how memory is managed is pretty dependent on the language.